# Python Object Inspector GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, code-inspection

What I would like is a handy GUI to inspect objects.  The dir() function just isn't enough sometimes!

What would happen would I would type view_object(module) and it would give me a GUI window that has

Features:
 - Tree-view representation, similar to a file-viewer.  This would let me see all the classes, and I could expand/contract these views.
 - selecting on any object lets me see any **doc** attributes.

Ideally it would also let me cntrl+click on an object (or some other command) and open up the tree-view on THAT object, within IT'S module!

This shouldn't be THAT hard to make, so I assume someone has made it, I'm just having a hell of a time finding it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) is really great. Especially debugger. I't heavy and it starts slowly, but it's a powerful tool.

Not only you can see a tree-view of any variable in a runtime but you can even modify it on the fly.

See Variables view:
[image]

Comment: PyDev is fantastic.  I used it for a while until I switched to Spyder (which is much more lightweight).  In doing so I lost some things.

I will try to boot up PyDev again if there is no other solution, but it would be great if there were a standalone application that I could run from the interpreter.  (Edit: I forgot that PyDev had this feature.  Thanks for reminding me)

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at 
[objbrowser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/objbrowser) (disclaimer I wrote it).

[image]

Comment: `PySide` doesn't seem to support Python 3.5, so I can't use your `objbrowser`. :(

Comment: @trevor-sullivan: I'm working on version 1.1, which supports Python 3 and PyQt4. I've pushed the [development branch](https://github.com/titusjan/objbrowser/tree/devel) to github so you can try it out if you want.